# How to merge list of dictionary into one dictionary in python, the value should be of list if the key has different values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries,

```
lst = [{'A':1,'B':2,'C':4},{'A':2,'B':2,'C':4},{'A':3,'B':2,'C':4}]
```

I want to merge this into one dictionary and put the values inside list if a key has different values.

```
desired output = {'A':[1,2,3},'B':2,'C':4}
```

I tried but it was resulting in something like,

```
{'A':[1,2,3},'B':[2],'C':[4]}
```

Comment: IMHO the result you get is better, the function(s) consuming the result wont have to check if it is a number or a list

Comment: @DaniMesejo But I want the resultant to be specific, if the values are different it should be list else it should be it's own datatype

Comment: Just transform the result you have now, like this:  `{ k : v if len(v) > 1 else v[0] for k, v in res.items()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this purpose:

```
from collections import defaultdict
lst =[{'A':1,'B':2,'C':4},{'A':2,'B':2,'C':4},{'A':3,'B':2,'C':4}]

d = defaultdict(list)

print(d)
#  defaultdict(list, {})

for x in lst:
  for k,v in x.items():
    d[k].append(v)

print(dict(d))

#  {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [2, 2, 2], 'C': [4, 4, 4]}
```

To get your desired result:

```
{ k : v if len(set(v)) > 1 else v[0] for k, v in d.items()}

#  {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': 2, 'C': 4}
```

Comment: `defaultdict`s also have `items` so no need to convert to a regular dict